# Search Results Rails SQL - Searching for users

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a search field in my navigation bar where people can search for other users, like fb's friend search.

In my Users table i have first_name and last_name as columns and would like the search results to look through both tables.  Right now I just have it working with the first name.

```
@usersfiltered = User.where("first_name LIKE?", "%#{params[:first_name]}%" )
```

Ideally, if there was an user named Bob Smith his name would come up if Bob, Smith, or Bob Smith was searched.

How would you go about adding to the SQL statement?  I've tried a few things but keep getting errors.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a symbol in your where method to pass in one value for multiple column like this:

```
@usersfiltered = User.where("first_name LIKE :search_name or last_name LIKE :search_name", 
                             search_name: "%#{params[:search_word]}%" )
```

**Update:**

To search for `first_name` and `last_name` combined, you could concatenate the two fields and add another `OR` condition.

The problem here is different databases have their own concatenation style.  Following are for MySQL and Postgres.

**MySQL:**

```
@usersfiltered = User.where("first_name LIKE :search_name or last_name LIKE :search_name or concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like :search_name", 
                             search_name: "%#{params[:search_word].squish}%" )
```

**Postgres:**

```
@usersfiltered = User.where("first_name LIKE :search_name or last_name LIKE :search_name or (first_name || ' ' || last_name) like :search_name", 
                             search_name: "%#{params[:search_word].squish}%" )
```

I also added the Ruby string function [squish](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish), to take care of extra spaces.

Comment: Tried this but if i type 'bob smith' it returns no results.  is there a way to add this logic?

Answer (score 0):

```
@usersfiltered = User.where("first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:first_name]}%", "%#{params[:last_name]}%")
```

However, if you have just one field that the user is typing into and you want to use it to search multiple names, I would think you'd want to name it something else besides "first_name" and use the approach described in the other answer.